# JOIN the same statement without WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts...
id INT(11),
time DATETIME,
...
```

And I want to know the highest ID in general, and I also want to know the latest post disregarding posts from the  last hour so I can subtract them to get the number of posts from the past hour.

I could do two queries:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS old_max FROM posts WHERE time < 
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

And

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max FROM posts;
```

But I'd like to have them in the same result set. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
Select 

(SELECT MAX(id) AS max from posts),

(SELECT 
MAX(id) AS old_max 

FROM posts WHERE time < 
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
SELECT (
SELECT MAX(id) AS old_max FROM posts WHERE time < 
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)),
(SELECT MAX(id) AS max FROM posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS old_max,
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM posts
        ) AS max
FROM posts
WHERE TIME < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
SELECT (
SELECT MAX(id) AS old_max FROM posts WHERE time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)),
(SELECT MAX(id) AS max FROM posts)
```